# connection to https with httpclient 4.1.2 gives org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

I have successfully used [this solution](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/android-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/) in **android** to post to https server accepting all certificates

Now i am trying the same thing in JAVA to post to https server accepting all certificates.

I modified the `EasySSLSocketFactory` class from the above url as `SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory` classes are deprecated in httpclient 4.1.2 version. `EasyX509TrustManager` class from the above url remains unchanged. Here is the `EasySSLSocketFactory` which i have modified.I have marked the classes which i have modified.

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;


public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SchemeSocketFactory
{
     private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

     private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
             try {
                     SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                     context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
                     return context;
             } catch (Exception e) {
                     throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
             }
     }


    private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
             if (this.sslcontext == null) {
                     this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
             }
             return this.sslcontext;
     }

     /**
      * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
      */
     public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
             return true;
     }

     // -------------------------------------------------------------------
     // javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
     // Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
     // for the correct operation of some connection managers
     // -------------------------------------------------------------------

     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
             return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(
                             EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
     }

     public int hashCode() {
             return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
     }

    //this method is modified
    @Override
    public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress,
            InetSocketAddress localAddress, HttpParams params) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {

        int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);
        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket(params));
        if (localAddress != null) {
            // we need to bind explicitly
            sslsock.bind(localAddress);
    }

    sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
    sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
    return sslsock;
    }

    //this method is modified
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(HttpParams arg0) throws IOException {
         return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

}
```

And here is my httpclient.This class is also modified because of using httpclient 4.1.2

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds
    public static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 50 * 1000; // milliseconds


    public MyHttpClient() {
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
        // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory to the ConnectionManager
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, new EasySSLSocketFactory()));

        //setting the httpparams
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        //params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 1);
        //params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE, new ConnPerRouteBean(1));
        params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
        //HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf8");

        return new SingleClientConnManager(registry);
    }

}
```

I am trying to connect in the following way

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        String newresponse = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try{
             DefaultHttpClient client = new MyHttpClient();
             try {        
                    HttpPost req = new HttpPost(my https url);
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
                    req.setEntity(formEntity);
                    HttpResponse resp = client.execute(req);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";
                    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + NL);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    newresponse = sb.toString();

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
                    }finally {
                        if (in != null) {
                            try {
                                in.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                LOGGER.error("IOException: ",e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
        } catch(Exception e){
            LOGGER.debug("Connection Exception: ",e);
        }
```

When i try to connect to https server in the above way i get

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.http.HttpException: Unable to establish route: planned = HttpRoute[{}->https://mysiteurlhere]; current = HttpRoute[{s}->https://mysiteurlhere]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:774)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:577)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
        ... 22 more
```

The server i am trying to access is using certificate from **verisign** which i don't have with me.So i am trying to accept all certificates.In the future i am going to change this.

Can anybody please make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `EasySSLSocketFactory` must also implement the `LayeredSchemeSocketFactory` interface if you want it to support SSL tunneling.

Comment: @oleg- Thanks for the response.I will try that and keep you posted.

Comment: @oleg- I tried implementing it and it works like a charm.Thanks you very much

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to register Scheme for SSLSockerFactory:

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(
    new Scheme("https", 443, SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory())
);
```